# Typeorm synchronize:true emptying manyToMany relationship table on entity change

Tags: typescript, sqlite, graphql, typeorm

I'm new to typeorm but I'm seeing a very strange issue with the `synchronize: true` functionality, set in my `ormconfig.js`. When I modify an entity with a ManytoMany relationship any data  that is in the join table before making the entity change, is gone after.

Here is my `Project` Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("project")
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column("text")
  name: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column("text", { nullable: true })
  cluster?: string;

  //project_groups
  @ManyToMany((type) => Group, (group) => group.projects, { lazy: true })
  @Field((type) => [Group], { nullable: true })
  @JoinTable()
  groups?: Group[];
}
```

Here is my `Group` Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("group")
export class Group extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => String)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column("text")
  name: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column("text")
  type: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column("text", { nullable: true })
  currency: string;

  @Field((type) => [Project])
  @ManyToMany((type) => Project, (project) => project.groups, { lazy: true })
  projects: Project[];

  //group_modifiers
  @ManyToMany((type) => Modifier, (modifier) => modifier.group, { lazy: true })
  @Field((type) => [Modifier])
  @JoinTable()
  modifiers: Modifier[];
}
```

If I add a new field to either the Group or the Project, the migration is automatically run and the following queries

```
query: CREATE TABLE "temporary_project" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "name" text NOT NULL, "cluster" text, "asdfa" text)
query: INSERT INTO "temporary_project"("id", "name", "cluster") SELECT "id", "name", "cluster" FROM "project"
query: DROP TABLE "project"
query: ALTER TABLE "temporary_project" RENAME TO "project"
```

Shouldn't the relationship table persist the data?

Answer (score 1):

The [synchronize option](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options) is really for development when you're changing your data model a lot, you should turn it off before deploying.

> synchronize - Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data. This option is useful during debug and development. As an alternative to it, you can use CLI and run schema:sync command.

Comment: Also I would guess you have something watching your code and restarting your server on changes, then when it starts up TypeORM is updating the data model for you and dropping the data.

Comment: A dev and deploy cycle should include generating a [migration](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations), and then that is run on the database to control when the changes are made, and that preserves the data.

Comment: Thx for the response. Definitely a bit bizarre that the default would be to drop data IMHO.